# Getting the Name of Key Pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this [jQuery.Hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) plugin.

While it triggers the events on keypress, I want to know the name of the key pressed.

So for this code:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+z', myCallback);
```

I want to get the value `alt+ctrl+z` inside `myCallback`

```
function myCallback(){
 // how to get the name of clicked key i;e `alt+ctrl+z` here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the value `alt+ctrl+z` inside `myCallback`

Since you're using the [jQuery.Hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) plugin, you can access the `keys` property on the `data` object of the `event` object that is passed:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+z', myCallback);
function myCallback(e) {
  console.log(e.data.keys); // alt+ctrl+z
}
```